# Kubernetes delete secret docker-registry error Unable to connect to the server: x509

Tags: docker, kubernetes, x509certificate, docker-registry, kubectl

I have create two secret docker-registrys using with these step:

```
$ kubectl create secret docker-registry my-secret --docker-username=burak --docker-password=deniz --docker-email=burak@...

$ kubectl create secret docker-registry secret --docker-username=burak --docker-password=deniz --docker-email=burak@...
```

After these step I tried to get deployment with using that:

```
$ kubectl get deployment
```

and I have faced to that ERROR:

> Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "minikubeCA")

and When I have tried to delete or get these secret docker-registrys,I faced to same Error.

How Can I delete these docker-registrys. Can you help me?.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the problem, I used the following steps to delete docker-secrets.

1. Check available secrets

   ```
   $kubectl get secrets
   ```
2. Delete using *name* :

   ```
   $kubectl delete secrets mydockercredentials
   ```

use the above command to delete secrets.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend rebuilding your cluster and taking care to not disrupt the TLS tokens that you get for `kubectl` to function correctly.